# CMD Command to create folder for each file and move file into folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need a command that can be run from the command line to create a folder for each file (based on the file-name) in a directory and then move the file into the newly created folders.

Example :

**Starting Folder:**

```
Dog.jpg
Cat.jpg
```

The following command works great at creating a folder for each filename in the current working directory.

```
for %i in (*) do md "%~ni"
```

**Result Folder:**

```
\Dog\
\Cat\
Dog.jpg
Cat.jpg
```

I need to take this one step further and move the file into the folder.

**What I want to achieve is:**

```
\Dog\Dog.jpg
\Cat\Cat.jpg
```

Can someone help me with one command to do all of this?

Answer (score 12):

The second command would be

```
for %i in (*) do move "%i" "%~ni"
```

EDIT: Added "" for the %i, based on and31415's comment. tnx.

Comment: Following on from that i'd say A)could combine them- `for %i in (*) do cmda && cmdb`  B)could echo first `for %i in (*) do @ECHO cmda && cmdb`  C)could add I think it's a /R to go through subdirs.

Comment: This command won't work when file names contain spaces. You should use something like this: `for %i in (*) do move "%~i" "%~ni"` Even that might not be good enough, as it can have side effects when the target folder don't exist (e.g files being "moved" over themselves, hence renamed). An easy solution would be to combine both commands, like this: `for %i in (*) do md "%~ni" && move "%~i" "%~ni"` The command assumes that the directories don't exist already.

Comment: Also, to expand barlop's comment, when you use `cmda && cmdb` then `cmdb` will be executed only if `cmda` was successful. If you were to use `cmda & cmdb` instead, then the second command would be executed regardless. In fact, a single ampersand (`&`) is just a command separator and the double ampersand (`&&`) is a *conditional* one. Commands which don't set an `errorlevel` value shouldn't be used with the latter.

Answer (score 10):

Just execute these commands in series:

For creating the folders for each file:

```
for %i in (*) do mkdir "%~ni"
```

For moving each file to its folder:

```
for %i in (*) do move "%i" "%~ni"
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: This worked, thank you, the other higher rated answer only removed extension from all the files.

Answer (score -1):

This will do it if you have some folders like: example years\Filename.mp4

```
1901\Filename.mp4 
1902\Filename.mp4
1903\Filename.mp4
```

it will list all the folder 1st level files; lists all *.mp4 and *.mkv
will create the 2 level folders with the filename
and will move all the same name files in the 1st level folder to the 2nd level folder, run it at the years base folder.

```
for /d %D in (*) do for %i in (%~fD\*.mp4,%~fD\*.mkv) do mkdir "%~dpi%~ni" && move "%~dpi%~ni.*" "%~dpi%~ni\"
```

If you don't have a 1st level YEARS folder you can just bypass the first for and run the 2nd step, run it at the filename base folder.

```
for %i in (*.mp4,*.mkv) do mkdir "%~dpi%~ni" && move "%~dpi%~ni.*" "%~dpi%~ni\"
```

The && will ensure that the previous mkdir %ERRORLEVEL% is 0 to run the move of the files

To test, use this:

```
for /d %D in (*) do for %i in (%~fD\*.mp4,%~fD\*.mkv) do echo "%~dpi%~ni" && echo "%~dpi%~ni.*" "%~dpi%~ni\"
```

Comment: Find left files: for /d %D in (\*) do for %i in (%~fD\\*) do echo "%~dpi%~fi"

Comment: for /d %D in (\*) do for %i in (%~fD\\*) do move "%~fi" "D:\TRASH\"