# Powershell-create folder for each file and move file into folder

Tags: powershell

I want to make exactly the same thing as the link below but written in powershell. Can you help me please?

[CMD Command to create folder for each file and move file into folder](https://superuser.com/questions/762113/cmd-command-to-create-folder-for-each-file-and-move-file-into-folder)

Comment: We can only help you write the script yourself.  We are not a script writing service.  If you put some effort into written the script, somebody, will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
> gci *.jpg -File | % {MD $_.BaseName;MV $_ -Destination $_.BaseName}

> tree /F
├───Cat
│       Cat.jpg
│
└───Dog
        Dog.jpg
```

To get help with the used aliases: `gcm gcm,gci,md,mv,%,tree`
To get help with the used cmdlets: `Get-Help gci` etc.