# Syntax error near unexpected token '(' while trying to move files

Tags: command-line, bash, syntax

So I'm trying to follow the solution from this thread: [CMD Command to create folder for each file and move file into folder](https://superuser.com/questions/762113/cmd-command-to-create-folder-for-each-file-and-move-file-into-folder) as I want to do the same thing OP of that thread wanted to.

I've manually created the folders before finding that thread.

However, when I try to `for %i in (*) do move "%i" "%~ni"` to put each file in its respective folder, I get the following error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

My files are named like this: x01.sql, x02.sql, x03.sql... Folders, correspondingly, are x01, x02, x03, and so on. There are no spaces, special, or non-ASCII characters in their names. I use GNU bash version 5.0.7(1).

How do I solve the error and make the files move each in their own folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU Bash and Windows CMD are different entities. This  [CMD Command to create folder for each file and move file into folder](https://superuser.com/questions/762113/cmd-command-to-create-folder-for-each-file-and-move-file-into-folder) is for Windows CMD.

For GNU Bash, you can follow [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219991/how-do-i-create-a-directory-for-every-file-in-a-parent-directory)

Comment: My bad, I didn't even notice that thread's OP used CMD. I'd suspect something if I did but it was 4am here. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying to run Windows batch command in GNU bash. that's why it's not working. 
as "Saurabh P Bhandari" suggested, use the following snippets from this link,
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219991/how-do-i-create-a-directory-for-every-file-in-a-parent-directory
make sure you cd into the parentfolder first.

```
for x in ./*.txt; do
  mkdir "${x%.*}" && mv "$x" "${x%.*}"
done
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thank you very much!